# Date that badge was earned does not contain year

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, badges

Checking my badges on SO I noticed that the information about my badges is not complete.
For example, there is no information about the year when a current badge was earned.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I think those are the badges you earned this year. try looking for the badges you earned last year. I can see year in your badges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Badges only show the year in the date earned if it was over a year ago (roughly). If no year is specified it simply means last time it was that date (for example, aug 15 means last August 15th)