# No year mark for some recent badges in the profile page even though other recent badges have it

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, dates

For some badges there are no year mark in the profile page, e.g.:

> [image: no year]

It's expected for the current year dates, but they are not.

Answer from the [possible duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223324/date-that-badge-was-earned-does-not-contain-year) says:

> Badges only show the year in the date earned if it was over a year ago.

In my case the date `Feb 9 '17` was **less than one year ago**, so there should be no year, but it's here. Probably my question should be rephrased in terms of "why I see a year mark if date was less than one year ago". Answer on possible duplicate is probably wrong then.

Comment: @ale according to answer on possible dup: *"Badges only show the year in the date earned if it was **over a year ago**"*. But `Feb 9 '17` was not over one year ago.

Comment: @alexolut considering the other question it's still a bug but the wrong dates are circled and the title doesn't match anymore.

Comment: It's actually *not* over a year as in 365 days. It displays the year if it's over 330 days ago, to be more exact.

Comment: @animuson is this because developers are not from Earth, but the planet where year contains 330 days? :)

Comment: Because if it's so recently in the future, people might file bug reports saying "I earned a badge in the future". If it's close enough, those behind UTC time may think it was awarded today, but shows up as the next day because UTC.